# Check for multiple patterns with preg_replace?

Tags: php, preg-replace, design-patterns

I am looking for a solution for validating submitted posts. I want to check if someone submits (within the post):

- An Iframe for embedding YouTube or Vimeo video, replacing the correct width used in the Iframe
- An URL, replaced by a HTML clickable link
- An image URL, replacing it by a HTML

I was able to find the correct regex's for each of these requirements, but using 3 seperate preg_replace functions causes interference. For example, detecting an URL will also detect the URL inside the Iframe.

I have searched for a solution on this, both on Stackoverflow as on the rest of the internet. But I am not an expert, so perhaps someone could help me out or direct me to the right tutorial/website/how-to...

Comment: You might try a pattern that finds URLs that aren't within tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is first match the iframes with preg_match, and then replace them with a placeholder.

Then you can do the replacements for urls/images. Then, replace the iframe placeholders back with the iframes you matched earlier.

You can generate unique sequential placeholders by using preg_replace_callback, so that you get to run some code to increment a $placeholder_id for each replacement.

This is a general strategy that can often greatly simplify complex parsing.

Comment: It has been a while, but I would like to come back to this. Could you explain how you use the preg_replace_callback?

I do not completely understand the callback function. What I need to do is: 

Find iFrames -> replace them with a placeholder    
Find images -> replace them with a placeholder   
Find URLs -> replace them with a placeholder   
        
And put it all back together...

Answer (score 1):

You can simply pass and array of URL patterns to `preg_replace()` like this:

```
$pattern_array = array(
    '/somepattern/',
    '/someotherpattern/',
    '/yetanotherpattern/',
)
$replacement_array = array(
    'somereplacement',
    'someotherreplacement',
    'yetanotherreplacement'
}

$result = preg_replace($pattern_array, $replacement_array, $subject_string);
```

Comment: I understand, thanks! But what do I do with the replacements, because 3 different patterns need 3 different replacements...

Comment: @DavidDuyff Just use an array for the replacement as well.  See edited answer.